# C++: Is there any reason to use uint64_t instead of size_t

Tags: c++, vector, integer, size-t

My understanding of `size_t` is that it will be large enough to hold any (integer) value which you might expect it to be required to hold. (Perhaps that is a poor explanation?)

For example, if you were using something like a for loop to iterate over all elements in a vector, `size_t` would typically be 64 bits long (or at least on my system) in order that it can hold all possible return values from vector.size().

Or at least, I think that's correct?

Therefore, is there any reason to use A rather than B:

A: `for(uint64_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++ i)`

B: `for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++ i)`

If I'm wrong with my explanation or you have a better explanation, please feel free to edit.

Edit: I should add that my understanding is that `size_t` behaves like a normal unsigned integer - perhaps that is not correct?

Comment: if you need a hard guarantee that your int will be 64 bits for whatever reason (usually byte manipulation). `size_t` can vary depending on your system and compile options

Comment: `size_t` is not guaranteed to be 64bit

Comment: If you use `uint64_t` on a 32-bit target you can get performance far from optimal.

Answer (score 13):

uint64_t is guaranteed to be 64 bits. If you need 64 bits, you should use it.

size_t isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits; it could be 128 bits in a future machine. So, keyword uint_64 its reserved by that :)

Comment: should be "guaranteed TO be"

Answer (score 10):

`size_t` is the return-type of `sizeof`.

The standard says it's a typedef of some unsigned integer type, and large enough to hold the size of any possible object.
But it does not mandate whether it is smaller, bigger, or the same size as `uint64_t` (a typedef for a fixed-width 64-bit unsigned integer), nor in the latter case whether it is the same type.

Thus, **use `size_t` where semantically correct.**
Like for the `size()` of a `std::vector<T>` (`std::vector` gets it's `size_type` from the used allocator, `std::allocator<T>` using `size_t`).

Comment: No offence, but `std::vector<T>::size()` returns `std::vector<T>::size_type`

Comment: Yes, and that comes from the allocator.

Answer (score 4):

The correct case would be `for(std::vector::size_type i ...`.

For the purpose of iterating through a vector, or something of that sort, you would be hard pushed to find a case where `size_t` isn't big enough, and `uint64_t` is,

Of course, on a 32-bit machine, `size_t` would typically be 32 bits, but you may want to deal with numbers larger than 4 billion, which would require more than 32 bits, and this is certainly a use-case fo `uint64_t`. In other words, `uint64_t` is guaranteed to be 64-bit, `size_t` is not 64 bits in all machines/architectures.

Answer (score 3):

No, `size_t` has absolutely no connection to "holding any integer value which you might expect it to be required to hold". Where did you get this?

`size_t` is supposed to be large enough to hold the byte-size of any continuous object in the given implementation. Conceptually, this is far less that "any integer value". The language does not guarantee that you are allowed to create objects that occupy the entire addressable storage, which means that `size_t` is conceptually not even enough to hold count of addressable bytes of memory.

If you wanted to tie "any integer value" to the memory size, then the appropriate type would be `uintptr_t`, which is conceptually larger than `size_t`. But I don't see any reason to tie "any integer value" to memory characteristics at all. E.g. even though `uintptr_t` is larger than `size_t`, it is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold the size of the largest file in your platform's file system.

The reason you can use `size_t` to iterate over `std::vector`'s elements is that vector is internally based on an array. Arrays are continuous objects, which is why their sizes are covered by `size_t`. But once you take into consideration a non-contiguous container, like `std::list`, `size_t` is no longer guaranteed to be sufficient to measure or index such containers.

`uint64_t` can easier be greater than `size_t`. But it is quite possible that you might have to work with integer values that don't fit into `uint64_t`.

Comment: `std::malloc` and `std::allocator` also use `std::size_t`.

Comment: Even `uintptr_t` might be too small. As there's no limit for the values in OPs description...

Comment: @tmlen: They do because they allocate *continuous* blocks of memory, i.e. they allocate arrays of bytes. For them it is perfectly appropriate to use `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::size_t` is defined as an unsigned integer type. Its length depends on the platform. `v.size()` will always return a value of type `std::size_t`, so option B is always correct.